# How to pass optional arguments to callback functions in typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, callback, arguments

I have a callback function which returns some data to the component.

```
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(
    private service: AppService
  ) {
    this.processSomething(true);
    this.processSomething(false);
  }

  private processSomething(isZoom: boolean = false) {
    this.service.handleAsyncResponses(
      this,
      this.processDataReceived
    );
  }

  private processDataReceived(
    attributeValueList: any,
    isZoom?: boolean
  ) {
    console.log("isZoom:", isZoom);
  }
}
```

I need to send some value isZoom parameter from the component and access the same in `console.log("isZoom:", isZoom)`. Now console.log is loggin undefined.

A working sample is here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-service-oqkfmf?file=app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you need to wrap the function call in local closure:

```
private processSomething(isZoom: boolean = false) {
    this.service.handleAsyncResponses(
        this, (attributeValueList: any) => {
            this.processDataReceived(attributeValueList, isZoom);
        }
    );
}
```

[changed example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-service-b6o4r4?file=app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 2):

I think you're getting a little lost.

I took the freedom to clean your stackblitz from non-used code and show you how to use callbacks : [you can check it there](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-service-xghvjy?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts).

Let's start with the component :

```
constructor(
  private service: AppService
) {
  this.processSomething(true);
  this.processSomething(false);
}

private processSomething(isZoom: boolean = false) {
  this.service.handleAsyncResponses(isZoom, this.processDataReceived);
}

private processDataReceived(isZoom: boolean) {
  console.log("isZoom:", isZoom);
}
```

You don't need to define your parameters as optional, since you give your `isZoom` value a default value, hence making it always defined.

As you can see, you don't need to pass your full object as an argument : the function can be called without it.

In your service, all you have left is

```
public handleAsyncResponses(zoom: boolean, callback: Function) {
  callback(zoom);
}
```

Simply call the function as you would in any other context. simply rename `this.processDataReceived(zoom)` with the name of the parameter (here it being `callback`).

This is how callbacks are handled.

Comment: I cannot pass zoom as a param to `handleAsyncReponses` method, zoom is just a examples. It can varry based on components.

Comment: And since it is a parameter, you can make it vary. You offered a stackblitz, I used it as a base. If you want something more developped, then please provide a [mcve] of it, so that I can explain it to you too.